# VueJS CSS conflicts

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I'm trying to separate css for my Landing page and my dashboard page once logged in.

For now I have placed the styling into the root landing and root dashboard.

So even thought of these components are completely separate and both have there own router-view, the css I add directly to one component in the  tags is impacting the other one? How is a separate component somehow getting styling declared in a different file?

Comment: Are you styles scoped? If not, do they share similar CSS classes? If they are not scoped and share similar classes, the styles will effectively be global and could effect each other.

Comment: I tried scope and while this does fix the issue, it messes up the css for components within router-view of my dashboard as they don't seem to inherit the scoped css in the parent

Comment: You should probably clarify in your question how scoped styles are specifically "messes up the css for your components". At minimum share the code you are having issues with. It sounds like you may simply need to restructure your CSS and use of classes in your components to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I have fixed it now. The styling was being inherited with scope, but my nav menu which was not a child was causing my css issue :) Thanks anyway